# Can anyone explain the first function of this jquery countdown timer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

I want to understand what's happening in the first function of this countdown timer. What what do parameters t, n signify? I have not seen these before and google has not helped my search. I got this sample [here](http://trulycode.com/bytes/easy-countdown-to-date-with-javascript-jquery/) Why is it not good to mix jQuery and Javascript in the example below as others have pointed out?

```
    (function (e) {
     e.fn.countdown = function (t, n) {
     function i() {
        eventDate = Date.parse(r.date) / 1e3;
        currentDate = Math.floor(e.now() / 1e3);
        if (eventDate <= currentDate) {
            n.call(this);
            clearInterval(interval)
        }
        seconds = eventDate - currentDate;
        days = Math.floor(seconds / 86400);
        seconds -= days * 60 * 60 * 24;
        hours = Math.floor(seconds / 3600);
        seconds -= hours * 60 * 60;
        minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
        seconds -= minutes * 60;
        days == 1 ? thisEl.find(".timeRefDays").text("day") : thisEl.find(".timeRefDays").text("days");
        hours == 1 ? thisEl.find(".timeRefHours").text("hour") : thisEl.find(".timeRefHours").text("hours");
        minutes == 1 ? thisEl.find(".timeRefMinutes").text("minute") : thisEl.find(".timeRefMinutes").text("minutes");
        seconds == 1 ? thisEl.find(".timeRefSeconds").text("second") : thisEl.find(".timeRefSeconds").text("seconds");
        if (r["format"] == "on") {
            days = String(days).length >= 2 ? days : "0" + days;
            hours = String(hours).length >= 2 ? hours : "0" + hours;
            minutes = String(minutes).length >= 2 ? minutes : "0" + minutes;
            seconds = String(seconds).length >= 2 ? seconds : "0" + seconds
        }
        if (!isNaN(eventDate)) {
            thisEl.find(".days").text(days);
            thisEl.find(".hours").text(hours);
            thisEl.find(".minutes").text(minutes);
            thisEl.find(".seconds").text(seconds);
        }
        else {
            alert("Invalid Date. Ex: 15 Wednesday 2015 10:00:00");
            clearInterval(interval)
        }
    }
    var thisEl = e(this);
    var r = {
        date: null,
        format: null
    };
    t && e.extend(r, t);
    i();
    interval = setInterval(i, 1e3)
   }    
  })(jQuery);
  $(document).ready(function () {
    function e() {
    var e = new Date;
    e.setDate(e.getDate() + 60);
    dd = e.getDate();
    mm = e.getMonth() + 1;
    y = e.getFullYear();
    futureFormattedDate = mm + "/" + dd + "/" + y;
    return futureFormattedDate
}
$("#countdown").countdown({
    date: "13 September 2015 13:00:00", // date being counted down to
    format: "on"
});
});
```

Comment: Type `1e3` in the browser console. It’s `1000`.

Comment: The exact code above yields 11 errors in jslint. So no, it's not a good code (without even trying to read it)

Comment: `1e3` it's 10 to the power of 3. And you can go on: `1e15` for ex.

Comment: also, using `e` argument name to *picture* `jQuery` or `$` is (*bad*) ...here you are asking.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan most of the errors in JSLint are because tabs and not spaces are used, could you be a bit more helpful, thanks.

Comment: Moderators I take it asking for help / clarification / understanding a PORTION specifically parameters in a function of a piece of code is not kosher here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure a lot of your confusion stems from the single letter variable names. In this function, e is jQuery ($ is almost always used, not e), r is an object containing default (null) event date and format, t is user-specified and overrides these defaults, n is a callback to be called when the `eventDate <= currentDate` (countdown is at or past 0).

On these two lines:

```
    eventDate = Date.parse(r.date) / 1e3;
    currentDate = Math.floor(e.now() / 1e3);
```

Date.parse takes the string event date, parses it to the standard date representation (milliseconds since midnight Jan 1 1970), and divides that by 1000 (1e3 is notation for 1x10^3 or 1000 -- not sure why they don't just type 1000).

The second line uses e.now (jQuery.now) to return the current time, which is divided by 1000, then rounded down.

Anything that is `jQuery.fn.<func name>` is extending jQuery by adding a new function. In this case it's adding the countdown function to jQuery wrapped objects. Of course it will only work properly if that element contains the classes referenced in the function. There are also a few things that need to be fixed for this to be a clean jQuery plugin.

I've not looked at other countdown code, but it would be hard to get much more basic than this.